# Reverse proxy for gitlab and taiga - docker

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab, reverse-proxy

I'm trying make load balancer with nginx about 4 hours and I don't have more ideas how to deal with it.

My plan is:

client -> nginx load balancer -> gitlab or taiga.io

For now my nginx conf:

```
upstream gitlab {
    server localhost:8081;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name git.localhost.com
    client_max_body_size 300M;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
        proxy_set_header Host           $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }
}
```

Gitlab working on localhost:8081 fine.
When I goes to git.localhost.com i see only 502 error with error log:

```
 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: git.localhost.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "git.localhost.com"
```

What I'm doing wrong?
I tried this: [Gitlab 5.3 behind nginx reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529046/gitlab-5-3-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy) and still does not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some discrepancy between `http://localhost:8081` (which works) and the location to which nginx is proxying your requests (which doesn't work).

Currently your `upstream` block is not being used.

In `proxy_pass`, try replacing `http://localhost:8081/` with `http://gitlab`.

Comment: I deleted the trailing slash at the end of http://localhost:8081/ and still 502 with error log:
loadbalancer_1     | 2017/08/21 20:34:13 [error] 6#6: *4 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: git.localhost.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://localhost/favicon.ico", host: "git.localhost.com", referrer: "http://git.localhost.com/"

Comment: Hmm, is that the only error message you get? Just because it can't get the favicon doesn't mean it shouldn't work. Maybe the trailing slash fix won't work because nginx sees your `upstream` block and tries to match `localhost` against an upstream block name instead of resolving it to 127.0.0.1. Did you try `http://gitlab`?

Comment: Yeah, you have right. It's stupid problem. Now it's works. Thanks!